# Receive array from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good day, Please check my script first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#findmynip").click(function() {
    $("#hasilnip").html('<img src="<?=base_url();?>assets_global/images/loader.gif">&nbsp; Please wait');
    var nipnnya = $("#nipnya").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        nip: nipnnya
      },
      datatpe: 'json',
      url: "<?=base_url();?>registrasi/cek_ada/",
      success: function(hslnip) {
        if (hslnip) {
          alert(hslnip);
          $("#name").html(hslnip);
          //How do i do this
          $("#name").html(hslnip['FullName']);
          $("#birthday").html(hslnip['BirthDate']);
        } else {
          $("#name").html('Failed');
        }

      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

What i want to is receive the ajax request to my html.

When i try to `console.log(hslnip);` the result is `{"FullName":"BUNGA","BirthDate":"1994-10-03 00:00:00.000"}`. Any help would be appreciated.

What i want to receive is

```
<div id='name'></div>
<div id='birthday'></div>
```

I made typo at this part : `datatpe: 'json',` and i change it to `dataType: 'json'`. It's working now, thans for helping guys.

Comment: what do you want to receive?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o0opjp45/) check the demo add it to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot remove an array in your situation. You can use It do build an HTML content which can be displayed in `hasilnama` element.

Change this:

`$("#hasilnama").html(hslnip);`

To this for example:

`$("#hasilnama").html('<span>Fullname: ' + hslnip.FullName  + '</span><br><span>Birthdate: ' + hslnip.BirthDate.substring(0, 10) + '</span>');`

Comment: I get this error in my console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined`

Comment: console.log(typeof hslnip.BirthDate); Run this code in console and tell me the result

Comment: I get this result undefined

Comment: `datatpe: 'json'` -> change It to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: oh god. Thanks bro, you really helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hslnip = {"FullName":"BUNGA","BirthDate":"1994-10-03 00:00:00.000"}

$('#name').text(hslnip.FullName)
$('#birthday').text(hslnip.BirthDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='name'></div>
<div id='birthday'></div>
```

Use `hslnip.FullName` and `hslnip.BirthDate`